# What can I do to debug the "Could not unzip extension" issue even after my upgraded extension got approved?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

When I try to install an extension on my browser, I got this issue:

[image]

I am the developer of this extension and it works perfectly on local. The extension even got approved by Chrome Web Store team.

How can this error happen? What can I debug?

I searched on Google but could not find related information.

Thanks